# python script stops after a while

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, nohup, http-request

I have a python script on an Amazon EC2 server that's requesting data from two different servers (using urllib and http.request), that data is then recorded on a text file. It has to be running for a long time. I am using nohup to get it running on the background.

The thing is, it stops after a while (sometimes it lasts 24 hours, sometimes 2 hours, it varies). I don't get an error message or anything. It just stops and the last string of characters received are just saved in the text file as an incomplete string (just the info that could read from the remote server).

What could be causing this problem?

This is the code I have:

```
import urllib3 #  sudo pip install urllib3 --upgrade
import time

urllib3.disable_warnings() # Disable urllib3 warnings about unverified connections
http = urllib3.PoolManager()

f = open('okcoin.txt', 'w')
f2 = open('bitvc.txt', 'w')

while True:
    try:
        r = http.request("GET","https://www.okcoin.com/api/v1/future_ticker.do?symbol=btc_usd&contract_type=this_week")
        r2 = http.request("GET","http://market.bitvc.com/futures/ticker_btc_week.js ")
    except: # catch all exceptions
        continue

    #Status codes of 200 if it got an OK from the server
    if r.status != 200 or r2.status != 200 or r.data.count(',') < 5 or r2.data.count(',') < 5: # avoids blank data, there should be at least 5 commas so that it's correct data
        continue; # Try to read again if there was a problem with one reading

    received = str(time.time()) # Timestamp of when the information was received to the server running this python code

    data = r.data + "," + received + "\r\n"
    data2 = r2.data + "," + received + "\r\n"        

    print data,r.status
    print data2, r.status

    f.write(data)
    f2.write(data2)

    time.sleep(0.5)
    f.flush() #flush files
    f2.flush()
f.close()
f2.close()
```

**EDIT:** I left the program opened using screen through ssh. It stopped again. If I press "CTRL+C" to stop it, this is what I get:

```
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "tickersave.py", line 72, in <module>
    r2 = http.request("GET","http://market.bitvc.com/futures/ticker_btc_week.js")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 68, in request
    **urlopen_kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 81, in request_encode_url
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **urlopen_kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 153, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 541, in urlopen
    **response_kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 284, in from_httplib
    **response_kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 104, in __init__
    self._body = self.read(decode_content=decode_content)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 182, in read
    data = self._fp.read()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 551, in read
    s = self._safe_read(self.length)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 658, in _safe_read
    chunk = self.fp.read(min(amt, MAXAMOUNT))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 380, in read
    data = self._sock.recv(left)
```

Any clues? Should I add timeouts or something?

Answer (score 0):

Collect all output of your program and you will find a very good hint about what is wrong. That is, definitely collect `stdout` and `stderr`. For this to happen, you might want to call your program like that:

```
$ nohup python script.py > log.outerr 2>&1 &
```

That collects both, stdout and stderr in the file log.outerr, and starts your program decoupled from the tty and in the background. Investigating `log.outerr` after your program has stopped working will probably be quite revealing, I guess.

Comment: It happened again. It stopped. But the log.outerr file doesn't have any error or anything! Only the output is there (the info being requested from the server). The last lines are simply incomplete, but no error or anything! Do you have any clue to what's going on?

Comment: An external event unexpectedly kills your script, with heavy means, so that it does not have a chance to report anything to stdout/err. Such an event would be SIGKILL, where the receiving process has no chance to respond to. That is, you  need to increase your debugging universe, and not only look at the script itself, but at the entire environment it is running in.

Comment: I see... Do you think this has something to do with the Amazon EC2 server? I basically ran the code at the same time on my computer and on the remote server. The script on my computer is still running, the Amazon one however, stopped... Is there anything within the Linux server that may be causing this? Thank you!

Comment: That's basically where we cannot help you anymore, because the problem is too broad. That can only be debugged with "hands-on" method. You need to investigate what happens to the Python process running your script.

Comment: Jan, I edited the question and added a few more details. Even if I tru to debug the program as much as possible with as much exception handlers as I can, I still don't get an specific error. It appears that it's hanging in the http request though when I press CTRL+C to close it that's what it shows.